# Cloudkit social app - how to start

Tags: swift, xcode6, server, cloudkit

I have a great app idea but im a not too experienced developer so i have no idea if it this is possible, I was thinking about a app were everyone has a unique username linked to their iCloud account (a easy way to find friends like snapchat) and every user can create a mission were they have to specify the objective, the reward and the usernames that they want to challenge.
How do i start with this? is it possible? Damn i have so many questions 
I already have a small client but im not sure if it will be cloud kit compatible

Thank you

Comment: This is not "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Refer to Apple's CloudKit documentation if you want to know what is possible: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html or a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial

Comment: It sounds like you need to start by watching Apple's WWDC videos about CloudKit, so that you can learn a little about what's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, If you want to start a social app that is based on CloudKit, then maybe you could try a quick start with: https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao
The user list is based on your address book contacts that also have installed the app and the chat functionality is already fully functional. Maybe you could play around with it and then come back to stack overflow with more specific questions.

Comment: that was the kickstart i was looking for thank you so much :)